# JPA -why is derived query returning Optional object?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

In my code `Appointment` is a entity and `Long id` is its primary key.

In the below code  when i write `findById(Long id)`, the return type required is `Optional`.
But when i write `findAppointmentById(Long id)`, the return type required is `Appointment`.

What is difference between `findById(Long id)` and `findAppointmentById(Long id)` ??

```
public interface AppointmentDao extends CrudRepository<Appointment, Long>{

    Optional<Appointment> findById(Long id);

}
```

Comment: The difference is `findById(id)` is already declared in the `CrudRepository` interface as returning an `Optional`, and overriding a return type of `Optional` with an unrelated `Appointment` type is not allowed in Java

Comment: But why does findAppointmentById(Long id) return Appointment ? Is it because its a derived query and since i wrote Appointment in the query ,it will return Appoinment?

Comment: No, it's because you declared it to return `Appointment`. You can declare it to return `Optional<Appointment>` and it will work just as well. You can put anything you like between `find...` and `...By`, Spring Data will simply ignore it

Comment: Thank you crizzis.I understand it now.

Comment: @crizzis could you make that in a proper answer, so OP can accept it, I can upvote it and everybody else sees the question is answered?

Comment: @JensSchauder I tend not to post answers to questions that bear a high risk of getting downvoted into oblivion, but since you explicitly asked for it - here you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is difference between findById(Long id) and findAppointmentById(Long id) ??

The difference is `findById(id)` is already declared in the `CrudRepository` interface as returning an Optional, and overriding a return type of `Optional` with an unrelated `Appointment` type is not allowed in Java

> But why does findAppointmentById(Long id) return Appointment ? Is it because its a derived query and since i wrote Appointment in the query ,it will return Appoinment?

No, it's because you declared it to return `Appointment`. You can declare it to return `Optional<Appointment>` and it will work just as well. You can put anything you like between `find...` and `...By`, Spring Data will simply ignore it.